# Kotlin - start activity after getting an alert and click OK

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

**UPDATE - Code has been updated. The function is working as expected. The following was added as well: intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) because when I was going back to the ResultsActivity, the previous activity were still available and that was affecting the workflow of the app. FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP removes previous activity.**

I can't get this to work properly. I have a function that once executed an alert comes up, I should be able to click OK and navigate back to an activity. The problem I'm having is that once the function runs, I see the message but it disappears and the app navigates back to an activity. I'm not sure how to see the alert, click OK and then navigate to the other activity. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

**My Activity**

```
class DischargeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
.....

private val patientDischarged = { _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
        Toast.makeText(this.applicationContext, android.R.string.yes, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

.....

  fun dischargePatientInfo() {
        val hospMd = intent.getStringExtra(ASSIGNEDMD)
        if (hospMd == loggedInUserName?.text) {
            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(PTLIST_REF).document(documentId)
                .update(
                    DISCHARGE_COMMENT, dischargeComment.text.toString(),
                    DISCHARGE_DATE, dischargeDateTxt.text.toString(),
                    DISCHARGE_STATUS, "yes"
                )

val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setTitle("DISCHARGE STATUS")
        builder.setMessage("Patient has been discharged")
            .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, id ->
            val intent = Intent(this@DischargeActivity, ResultsActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("HospCode", hospDischargeLbl?.text)
                intent.putExtra("UserSpecialty", loggedInUserSpecialty?.text)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            startActivity(intent)
            }
        builder.show()

        } else {
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this part of the code

```
with(builder) {
            setTitle("DISCHARGE STATUS")
            setMessage("Patient has been discharged")
            setPositiveButton("OK", DialogInterface.OnClickListener(function = 
this@DischargeActivity.patientDischarged))
            show()
        }
        val resultsActivity = Intent(this, ResultsActivity::class.java)
        resultsActivity.putExtra("HospCode", hospDischargeLbl?.text)
        resultsActivity.putExtra("UserSpecialty", loggedInUserSpecialty?.text)
        startActivity(resultsActivity)
```

You are starting `ResultsActivity` when you are creating the dialog.

This should work

```
setPositiveButton("OK") { dialogInterface, i ->

    Toast.makeText(this@DischargeActivity, android.R.string.yes, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    val resultsActivity = Intent(this, ResultsActivity::class.java)
    resultsActivity.putExtra("HospCode", hospDischargeLbl?.text)
    resultsActivity.putExtra("UserSpecialty", loggedInUserSpecialty?.text)
    startActivity(resultsActivity)
}
```

Comment: hello Max, I made the changes but here patientDischarged() is telling me "no value passed for parameter p1 and p2". Any ideas? thank you

Comment: Intent throws an error: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied... Context!, String! Uri!.